# Meteor.js - saving only to clientside collections

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, how would I go about saving to a collection that's defined on both the client and the server but stopping it from saving to the server? I want to control when I save to a clientside collection and when I subsequently save to the server, is this possible in Meteor?

Comment: Why not having one different collection on each side and periodically pushing the changes of the client collection?

Comment: So just have different names for the collections...seems like Meteor automatically syncs collections with the same name, is that right?

Comment: I guess so. One thing you could do is observe the changes on the client collection, store them, and push them using a `Meteor.setInterval` or something. Would you like me to post an example as an answer if it fits your issue?

Comment: sure please do, I am a bit unclear on this when really pushed on the details

Comment: You can do `new Mongo.Collection(null)` on the client to make a collection which isn't synced at all.

Comment: This package sounds like it does what you're looking for: https://github.com/richsilv/meteor-dumb-collections

Comment: @Kyll you might be interested in what was posted on this thread since you last commented

Comment: Yes, I was happy to discover that new package after having written a couple dozen lines of answer!

Comment: word that is the life bro :)

Comment: write your answer here anyway it will probably help